# Not able to receive Facebook chat messages

Tags: facebook-messenger

I am having trouble receiving my chat messages.  How do I turn it on?  I have searched and I was told to click on the gear box at the bottom of chat.  it does not show one.

Comment: You're using the web interface, right? Not a smartphone app?

Answer (score 6):

If you are logged in to Facebook I think you should see (having scrolled down) something like:

[image: WA112643 example]

The 'gear box' is the one labelled `Options` in the image and you would need to select it and `Turn on chat`.